# How to save a property to a mongoose document post save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I'm using Mongoose's `timestamps` schema option to make a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` property on a user schema (calling them "applicants"). The only reason I need this is to figure out how long it takes a user to get through the signup process. When they click the "Let's get started" button, it creates the user on the backend and sets the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties (at this point, they are equal). Then when they finish the signup process, I want to send another call to the db and force the document to save again, thus updating the `updatedAt` property. Once that occurs, I want to find the time difference between the two timestamp properties to see how long it took them to finish the process, then save that value to a `timeTaken` property.

Problem is, the only way I'm seeing to do this is to trigger the save, then in the promise that's returned, save the document again after a "post save" hook runs to update the applicant's document.

Probably will make more sense with the code:

#### Applicant's Schema

```
var applicantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    timeTaken: String
}, {timestamps: true});

applicantSchema.post("save", function () {
    this.setTimeTaken();
});

applicantSchema.methods.setTimeTaken = function () {
    var applicant = this;
    var ms = this.updatedAt - this.createdAt;
    var x = ms / 1000;
    var seconds = Math.floor(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(x % 24);
    applicant.timeTaken = hours + "h:" + minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";
};
```

#### Applicant Router

```
applicantRouter.put("/:applicantId", function (req, res) {
    Applicant.findById(req.params.applicantId, function (err, applicant) {
        applicant.save().then(function () {
            applicant.save(function (err, applicant) {
                //console.log(applicant.timeTaken);
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send(err)
                } else {
                    res.send({success: true, timeTaken: applicant.timeTaken})
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

#### How this works:

`PUT` request comes in, mongoose searches mongodb for the document with the given id, then triggers a "save" event. It's caught by the schema's "post save" hook, which calls the document's `setTimeTaken` method. This method updates the property on the document, but since this happens **post** save, I need to save it again to get it to persist.

I can't use a pre-save hook, because it won't have updated the `updatedAt` property yet.

The code above actually works, but I kinda hate myself for writing it this way. I feel like an infomercial actor: "There's *got* to be a better way!"

Or maybe there isn't? Someone who knows this stuff better ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I should just not use the timestamps option and manually set `createdAt` to a `Date.now` default, then pre-save do all the math and set `timeTaken` to the pre-save time...

Comment: Well the standout options would be to rather "pre" save to calculate the value, or possibly live with a virtual field instead if "queries" using that calculated value are not required. Any such plugins will be attached to the "pre" save hooks anyway, which is how they actually persist. If a "pre" did not work for you then it would just be because of middleware order.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The reason a "pre save" won't work is because before it gets saved, the `updatedAt` timestamp is still at the old time. When it actually gets saved is when the `updatedAt` timestamp updates, and since I need that value to be accurate in order to calculate the time difference, I resorted to "post save".

As to "virtual fields" instead of "queries" - I don't even know what a virtual field is, but I'll look it up and see how it could help. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time understanding your comment :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stepping away from the computer for a few hours I realized I was adding too much complexity and trying too hard to use the built-in `timestamps` option. I just changed my math to include `Date.now() - this.createdAt`, changed the `post save` to a `pre save`, and got rid of the extra `applicant.save()`:

#### Applicant's Schema:

```
var applicantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    timeTaken: String
}, {timestamps: true});

applicantSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.setTimeTaken();
    next();
});

applicantSchema.methods.setTimeTaken = function () {
    var applicant = this;
    var ms = Date.now() - this.createdAt;
    var x = ms / 1000;
    var seconds = Math.floor(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(x % 60);
    x /= 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(x % 24);
    applicant.timeTaken = hours + "h:" + minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";
};
```

#### Applicant Router:

```
applicantRouter.put("/:applicantId", function (req, res) {
    Applicant.findById(req.params.applicantId, function (err, applicant) {
        applicant.save(function (err, applicant) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err)
            } else {
                res.send({success: true, timeTaken: applicant.timeTaken})
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Works like a charm.